# Why is there no InterlockedExchangeSubtract64?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

On the WindowsAPI, there are

- `InterlockedExchangeAdd`
- `InterlockedExchangeAdd64`
- `InterlockedExchangeSubtract`

Why is there no `InterlockedExchangeSubtract64`?

I want to do atomic operations on 64-bit values (`LONGLONG`) without having to use a mutex.

Comment: Because it's unnecesarry.

Comment: @JohnDibling Perhaps a better question would be why `InterlockedExchangeSubtract` exists!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Indeed.

Comment: InterlockedExchangeSubtract exists to handle the case where the addend is INT_MIN. Negating the addend and using InterlockedExchangeAdd when the value is INT_MIN invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply negate the operand that you pass to `InterlockedExchangeAdd64`. In other words, use the fact that `x - y` is equal to `x + (-y)`.

Comment: I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have a good enough reputation yet. Thanks though!

Comment: If someone gives you y=INT_MIN, you're invoking undefined behavior by negating it.